# Visual C# periodic routine picking up text value from box before fully entered

Tags: textbox

I have a periodic "Periodic Task" that will read a text box for a value for further processing.

The text box has a default value, and things work as expected there.

However, if the user tries to enter a value, the application crashes, because Convert.ToDouble(inputbox.Text) is called before the user can input a full value.

I *could* consider slowing down the task, but that might only hide the issue.

I think the solution is to use an event for the text box, but what event should be used to signal that the user is fully done?  (I could see the same issue happening once if a user starts entering the "1." of 1.234, and Convert.ToDouble still crashes)